# Words to describe human beauty?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am listing down words that I can use to compliment a special someone. So far, I have a few like "gorgeous", "stunning", "mesmerizing", "ineffable" , "pretty" , "charming" , etc.

These are common and far too few. Are there more words that can be used to describe the beauty of a young girl in her late teens?   If the words are context-sensitive then please do mention that also.

Comment: Breathtaking, divine, angelic, inspiring, dreamlike, sensational, ephemeral, there are too many to mention. And if yo allow for multiple-word expressions, there is a _world_ and a _history_ of poetry available to you. I would suggest you start by calling your special "female" a woman or a girl :)

Comment: Might I suggest a [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/beautiful)?  This is very much 'general reference'.

Comment: If you're hoping to woo, you might do better to drop *female* as a noun in such contexts before acquiring new adjectives.

Comment: ok I have tried my best to narrow down the scope. Please reconsider the question for opening.

Answer (score 1):

ravishing, easy on the eyes, a headturner, a looker, a sight for sore eyes, a vision...

Comment: The word "siren" also means a very attractive woman who's also dangerous.

Comment: "Siren" if she is attractive, dangerous and has a loud, whiny voice?

Comment: ...or a femme fatale?

Comment: As an Engineer, I like to quantify things. The traditional unit of female beauty is the milliHelen, defined as the amount of beauty necessary to launch a single ship.

Comment: and, of course, enchantress, seductress, vamp, sexpot...I believe we can go on and on with this...:-)